# Tomcat webapp's file path under multiple OS

Tags: java, python, eclipse, macos, tomcat

Java Code :

```
//Gives the webapp directory
String pythonScriptPath =  getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
//Gives OS name
String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

if (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
pythonScriptPath = pythonScriptPath + "scripts\\data_parser.py";
} else if ((OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0) {
    pythonScriptPath = pythonScriptPath + "scripts/data_parser.py";
}

String[] cmd = new String[3];
cmd[0] = "python";
cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;
cmd[2] = "2013-09-10T08:00:00-04:00";

// create runtime to execute external command
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
```

This code runs fine in a Mac machine. The problem is in windows machine. I'm trying to get the python file under "scripts" directory and execute it. My program was able to find the file in Mac, but not in Windows.

File under Windows : C:\Users\Administrator\TEST.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\TEST\scripts\data_parser.py

File under Mac :
/Users/satishjonnala/TEST/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/TEST/scripts/data_parser.py

Comment: have you tried os.path.join(pythonScriptPath, "scripts", "data_parser.py") ?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Do I need to run Python program from Windows system in a different way. I removed "#!/usr/bin/env python" and updated "cmd[0] = "C:\\Python\\python";" to run from windows. It shows "exception.WindowsError" from TomCat

Comment: @aglassman, I'm getting as below -
The page at localhost:8080 says:
data : 2013-09-10T08:00:00-04:00
Problem : <type'exception.WindowsError'>

Answer (score 0):

Have you see the class [`org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) of [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). The method:

```
public static String separatorsToSystem(String path)
```

> Converts all separators to the system separator.

Comment: I think its able to find the correct path. But there's is problem in running my python script form windows program. Thanks for your suggestion though.